# How to prevent color change in a option item from and selected element in html when is checked and lost focus?

Tags: css, html-select, checked

I have a stylized SELECT element.
When I click and element every work fine.
But if change the focus, the checked element change the color.

Here is the code:

```
<style>
  .extracts-view__select-menu {
  font-family: 'OpenSansRegular', Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -20px;
  border: 0;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 26.4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  }
  .extracts-view__select-menu:focus {
  border: 0;
  outline: none; 
  }
  .extracts-view__menu-item {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #18A592;
  box-shadow: inset 368px 38px #FFFFFF; 
  }
  .extracts-view__menu-item:hover {
  outline: 1px solid #18A592; 
  }
  .extracts-view__menu-item:checked {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: inset 368px 38px #18A592;
  font-weight: bolder; 
  }
</style>

 <p>Hello World !</p>

 <select 
     size="5" 
     class="extracts-view__select-menu">

  <option class="extracts-view__menu-item">Transferencia banco de españa</option>
  <option class="extracts-view__menu-item">Extracto integrado</option>
  <option class="extracts-view__menu-item">Embargos</option>
  <option class="extracts-view__menu-item">Domiciliaciones</option>
```

Here is the same code for review: http://jsbin.com/yeziwi/edit?html,output

The steps for reproduce the error are:

Click on a option, then click in "Hello World". The color of the checked option change to black.

I want to be white.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use pseudo class :active  not checked

```
.extracts-view__menu-item:active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: inset 368px 38px #18A592;
  font-weight: bolder; 
  }
```

Could be also a set of the browser, you can make a normalize and add

```
a:active{your code}
```

Comment: I would like to give you +1 to your vote, but my low rating still will not let me.

It is very strange what happens, because with different users in google chrome, behavior differs from one another.

Anyway. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks! i know me too still have some limitation in this form! happy to help you. yes normally depend form the browser not from user, but could be they  have some set on their chrome, or have older version. or maybe some cookies have chance the preset. I don't know it's just a supposition!